# Which application mode should I use in Azure Notification Hubs for Testflight betas?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I am using Azure Notification Hubs for sending notifications.
It worked fine when I tried it a few times on my development iOS device.

But now I want to distribute the app to testers via iTunes Connect / Test Flight and the notifications have stopped working.

I am unsure as to which application mode in Azure Notification Hubs that is the correct to use with Test Flight betas? Sandbox or Production?
I have tried both without any luck.

This is for a Xamarin Forms app and I am using V4 of the Azure Mobile Client. Is there anywhere I need to disable sandbox mode in the app itself?

I am currently registering using this bit of code:

```cs
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    if (deviceToken != null)
        App.Client.GetPush().RegisterAsync(deviceToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it started working "by itself" after a little while.
I chose Production for the Test Flight betas and there was no notifications coming through.
After waiting an hour or so it seemed to fix itself - now notifications are coming through just fine.

So maybe the lesson is when you change from Sandbox to Production you need to wait a bit before things work again.

Comment: If you install a TestFlight build on top of an Xcode debug build, it won't work reliably. You need to remove the debug build from the phone before installing the TestFlight build. This may be the issue you ran into.

Comment: Thanks - I think that could be it.